# Anyone have an idea how to express complex join logic within a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've been at it all day. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to translate either of the final two select statements found within the below code snippet:

```
declare @Person table
(
    [Name] varchar(50),
    [ABA] varchar(9)
)

declare @Entity table
(
    [Name] varchar(50),
    [Respondent] varchar(9),
    [TierRespondent] varchar(9)
)

insert into @Person ([Name], [ABA])
select 'Steve', '000000001'
union
select 'Mary', '000000002'
union
select 'Carey', '000000003'

insert into @Entity ([Name], [Respondent], [TierRespondent])
select 'Steve', '000000001', '000000006'
union
select 'Mary', '000000004', '000000002'
union
select 'Carey', '000000005', '000000008'


select *
FROM @Entity e
LEFT JOIN @Person p
        ON p.[ABA] = e.Respondent
        or p.[ABA] = e.[TierRespondent]

select *
FROM @Entity e
LEFT JOIN @Person p
        ON p.[ABA] in (e.Respondent ,e.[TierRespondent])
```

The thing that boggles my mind is the logic found within the ON clause of the join statements.

I'm not a SQL wiz, so I've even failed at trying to restructure these SELECT statements into a different form that gives me the same results, but is also easier to translate to LINQ.

Any ideas, anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Linq-to-Entities with Entity Framework? If so, do you have foreign-key constraints defined? If so, then you don't need to write a Linq query at all, you can simply use the Navigation Properties members of your Entity objects.

Comment: Using EF, but no foreign key relationships. I have to join data from two different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of pondering, I found the following sql to be an acceptable refactoring that can easily be translated to a linq query:

```
select *
from @entity e
left join @Person p
    on 1 = 1
        where p.[ABA] = e.Respondent
        or p.[ABA] = e.[TierRespondent]
        and p.ABA is not null
```

And here is the corresponding linq query:

```
from entity in entities
join p in persons on 1 equals 1 into groupJoin
from person in groupJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
where person.ABA == entity.Respondent || person.ABA == entity.TierRespondent
&& person.ABA != null
select new
{
    entity.Name,
    entity.Respondent,
    entity.TierRespondent,
    person?.Name,
    person?.ABA
}
```

The select statements of the original post contained logic within the join clause. This logic cannot be expressed within a linq join clasue. This refactoring moves the logic from the join, and into the where clause, which can easily be handled expressed in linq.